# Was the Quran intended to be a book?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, revelation

Did Muhammad actually instruct people to make a book out of the Quran and spread it around the world? It seems that this process began after his death and I'm wondering if Muhammad actually ordered for this to happen.